# GZipInputSteam DeCompression did not work for a data of size more than 13239

Tags: c#, java, compression

I have created compression and decompression technique using GZipinputstream in both c#.NET and Java. If I compress up to 13239 bytes in c#.NET then i can decompress it in Java but if I compress more than 13239 bytes in c#.NET then i am not able to decompress it in Java. But I can decompress it using C#.NET. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks
Bapi

Answer (score 1):

Flush the stream before closing it / trying to read it from the Java side. My guess is that you hit some kind of buffer and not all data is transfered.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try compressing with gzip, gunzip to see where the cause of the problem is.

I have compressed and decompressed much larger files with Java, and these worked correctly with the utilities as well.